# How to run a class from a jar with from command-line with classpath specified

Tags: java, jar, classpath, executable-jar, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to run a class from a JAR. This class is NOT the only main class in this jar. Also, it requires number of other jar files, which I have kept in the same directory as this Jar. The commands I have tried are as follows:

(mydir is the directory in which all of my jars are located, using Windows platform)

`mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar` is needed for `myProjImport.jar` to run and `com.mycomp.myProj.importer.csv.TestImporter` is the class i am trying to run. 
`"C:\Documents and Settings\user\workspace\myProjImport\src\conf\datasource.properties"` and `"C:\temp\apollo_claims_test.txt"` are the command line arguments required by the class `TestImporter`
Here is what I have tried:

```
mydir>java -cp C:\temp\test_myProj\mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar;. myProjImport.jar com.mycomp.myProj.importer.csv.TestImporter "C:\Documents and Settings\user\workspace\myProjImport\src\conf\datasource.properties" "C:\temp\apollo_claims_test.txt"
```

And here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myProjImport/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myProjImport.jar
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: myProjImport.jar.  Program will exit.
```

Can someone please tell me what exact command should I run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try:

`java -cp C:\temp\test_myProj\mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar;myProjImport.jar com.mycomp.myProj.importer.csv.TestImporter "C:\Documents and Settings\user\workspace\myProjImport\src\conf\datasource.properties" "C:\temp\apollo_claims_test.txt`"

provided your running this from the same direcotry as myProjImport.jar

Comment: Right idea, add myProjImport.jar to the classpath. But use `;` separator on Windows.

Comment: opps in that case: java -cp C:\temp\test_myProj\mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar;myProjImport.jar com.mycomp.myProj.importer.csv.TestImporter "C:\Documents and Settings\user\workspace\myProjImport\src\conf\datasource.properties" "C:\temp\apollo_claims_test.txt

Comment: Thanks Karthik and ykaganovich, your solution works. Karthik, please make the correction which ykaganovich has suggested- ';' instead of ':' since this is for Windows platform.

Answer (score 2):

When -jar option is specified, any other class path options are ignored. So this won't work:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar -classpath foo.jar
```

But if you place foo.jar name into META-INF/manifest.mf within MyJar.jar:

```
Class-Path: foo.jar
```

Then the foo.jar will be searched on the same level as MyJar.jar, i.e. in the same directory.

Sometimes I just unpack all dependent JARs and pack their content into MyJar.jar. Fewer dependencies this way.

Comment: After adding the line "Class-Path mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar", I got this error: "Invalid or corrupt jarfile myProjImport.jar"

Comment: I don't want to be guilty of java bashing, but why? why? why? can I not specify extra class paths when running a jar??