# executing jar from command line with jars inside

Tags: java, jar

I saw [running jar from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891343/how-to-run-a-class-from-a-jar-with-from-command-line-with-classpath-specified).

However my case is different. I put the jars needed for the main class under lib folder. So my jar is like this:

```
lib
META-INF
VideoFieldsResults.class
```

in the META-INF I have:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: VideoFieldResults
```

when I try to run:

```
java -jar VideoFormat.jar onBa32hgnBg,Lh-BKkLYYBU C:\VideoFormat2.csv
```

Where the last 2 are arguments I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdata/util
/ServiceException
```

Which does exists under one of the jars inside!

How can I run a command line specifying that all the jars under lib folder inside are required for the jar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Classpath including JAR within a JAR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Java cannot load jars from within jars. To accomplish this, you would need a classloader that can handle it. For example [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/). There are other options as well (depending on how set you are with including jars inside of a jar or if flattening jars is an option), I'd recommend the answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar)