# how to deploy a java web application on cloud tomcat server

Tags: apache, tomcat, netbeans, publish, netbeans-8

there's a way to publish my changes on tomcat server from netbeans like visual studio has? in other words how can i register a tomcat server on cloud to publish my changes easily, i am actually doing it on with remote desktop upload WAR file and deploy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Deploy a jar File on a remote server from within Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184441/how-to-deploy-a-jar-file-on-a-remote-server-from-within-netbeans)

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the `Manager` webapp (ships with Tomcat), you can enable administrative operations such as `deploy` where you can upload a WAR file to deploy onto a running Tomcat.

See [Tomcat's User's Guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Archive_(WAR)_Remotely) for more information.